# Draw a binary tree for a complex mathematical expression

Tags: python, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have to draw a binary tree for the expression : `(e^-at)sin(bt-c)` but i have no clue what to do or where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binary Tree for the given expression
[image: Solution]